# Buffering polygon Openlayers 3

Tags: angular, openlayers-3, projection

I have the following method used to read a feature, buffer it then add back to an openlayers 3 map.

The operation works very well with square and rectangles polygons. However when it comes to shapes such as circles, the end result is a square.

How can I tweak the method in order to cater for circular polygons?
Read the number of points present in the polygon and then dynamically calculate and generate the bufferedExtent array values?

```
BufferFeatureAlternative(bufferAmount) {
    let state = this._store.getState(),
        tmpFeature = state.map.feature.feature_object;

    let poitnExtent = tmpFeature.getGeometry().getExtent(),
        bufferedExtent = new ol.extent.buffer(poitnExtent, bufferAmount),
        bufferPolygon = new ol.geom.Polygon(
            [
                [
                    [bufferedExtent[0], bufferedExtent[1]],
                    [bufferedExtent[0], bufferedExtent[3]],
                    [bufferedExtent[2], bufferedExtent[3]],
                    [bufferedExtent[2], bufferedExtent[1]],
                    [bufferedExtent[0], bufferedExtent[1]]
                ]
            ]
        ),
        bufferedFeature = new ol.Feature(bufferPolygon);

    let source = this.vectorSource.getSource();
    source.clear();
    source.addFeature(bufferedFeature);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JSTS library to do such actions.

Here is an official example to buffer lines, but it may be implemented for polygons, in the same way.
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/jsts.html

Comment: Tried that however does not work on maps with projection '27700', generates an error.

Comment: Unless you provide a fiddle to demostrate your case it is realy hard to guide you